# Light Weight Java Game Librayry, lots of static

Tags: java, static, lwjgl

Why does the light weight java game library use a lot of static references. I have been starting to learn LWJGL and i seem that LWGJL wants a lot of your variable and stuff to be static. I there a way around that and if not, what is the benefit of using a lot of static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because LWGJL is a Java wrapper around an implementation of OpenGL written in C, which is not object oriented.

You can find this in [the LWGJL wiki](http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=General_FAQ#Why_does_LWJGL_use_a_static_API_as_opposed_to_an_Object_Oriented_one.3F):

> Libraries like OpenGL, OpenCL and OpenAL are written in C and hence
>   static in nature. As LWJGL is designed to be as simple and as close to
>   the metal as possible its API is almost entirely static to allows it
>   to match as closely as possible to them.

Comment: Do you mean that LWGJL is written that way because it is not possible to write an OO wrapper over a library that is not OO?

Comment: No, I just mean that that was there reason. From the [LWGJL FAQ: "Libraries like OpenGL, OpenCL and OpenAL are written in C and hence static in nature. As LWJGL is designed to be as simple and as close to the metal as possible its API is almost entirely static to allows it to match as closely as possible to them."](http://lwjgl.org/wiki/index.php?title=General_FAQ#Why_does_LWJGL_use_a_static_API_as_opposed_to_an_Object_Oriented_one.3F)